# For a group $G$, if $x$ is a commutative element, then is $x^{-1}$ also a commutative element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am currently going through Dummit/Foote's *Abstract Algebra*, and was asked to prove the above for a specific case but was wondering if it holds in the general case.

I have a feeling it might be false but I am bad at coming up with counterexamples so I tried to think of some simple contradictions if it were to be true but didn't get anywhere. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: By a commutative element, I mean that for any element $y\in G$, we have that $xy=yx$.

Comment: By "$x$ is a commutative element," do you mean $x$ is in the center of $G$?

Comment: Sorry about that, I added it onto the post now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For any $y \in G$, we have $xy = yx$. Multiplying from the right and left each with $x^{-1}$, we get $yx^{-1}=x^{-1}y$. One can say even more, the set of commutative elements forms a subgroup, called the center of $G$.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $xa = ax$ iff $xax^{-1} = a$. Multiplying both sides by $x^{-1}$ shows that $x^{-1}xax^{-1} = ax^{-1} = x^{-1}a$.